# Export to excel option not work for FBA site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

I have publishing site where i am using the FBA authentication with custom login page. Everything is working fine but when i am trying to export to excel from list its not work.

Even i am not able to open site into the sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a fiddler trace to track down the issue?  What version of office are you using?  FBA is only supported on Office 2007 or later.

Comment: I have trace from the fiddler but no luck. I am using 64 bit 2010 office version. Even my site not open with the sharepoint designer as well. For the temporary basis i have created the extended site on windows authentication. Will update if found anything .....

Comment: the 64 bit office 2010 might be the issue.  Are you also running 64 bit IE?  I could be mistaken, but I think for some of these options in SP to work correctly, you have to run the same architecture for both office and IE.  So if you have x86 office installed, you run the x86 version of IE.  If you have x64 office installed, you run x64 IE.  I do know that some plugins used to have issues with x64 IE such as flash.  So unless you need the extra memory for excel or something, I would suggest always installing the x86 version of office.

Comment: After wasting day i found the problem. I dont know the reason.

Comment: My client has the requirement of the stylish popup instead of the default one. So we have using the poplayer for the same. For integration we have added the container TABLE & DIV for the iframe inside the master page. This is the iFrame code. <iframe frameborder=0 border=0 src="" name="PopLayer_ChildFrame" id="PopLayer_ChildFrame"></iframe>

Comment: When i remove this code then my custome login page work perfectly. I am really dont understand this strange behaviour. So i have decided to create separate master page for my login page. Now its working fine. I still not happy because i dont get the reason....Will work on free time and update you....Thanks for your help & comments

Comment: Good to know.  Very interested in what you figure out.  Thanks.